# Indesign CC - Another box inside my text box?

Tags: adobe-indesign, text

I have a text box in a document (Indesign CC) that seems to have another box inside of it. It looks like a border-type frame, and it is not resizable like the actual text box. I have attached a screen shot. The red border is obviously the normal text box, but the orange border is the mystery box. Can anyone tell me what this is?

[image: text box example]

Answer (score 1):

`Object > Text Frame Options . .`

The **Inset Spacing options** controls how close text is allowed to get to the edges of the text frame. This is what is indicated by the *inner* frame.

[image]

Comment: @Piper You might also want to check `Window > Styles > Object Styles`. If you double click the currently selected object style and go to `Text Frame General Options`, you can find the same thing.